# Is Asuka Langley-Soryu disgusted by Shinji?

Tags: evangelion

At the end of *[The End of Evangelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Evangelion)* Asuka says

> "*How disgusting*".

**Do we know what she meant by that? Is the world that's disgusting now or is she referring to Shinji's actions earlier in the film?**

Comment: This question assumes that the end of Evangelion *actually makes sense*.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by "hate?" Being disgusted and hating can mean different things.

Comment: Hate means experiencing extreme disgust at even looking at Shinji.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting "opinion-based" on this when we have an actual comment from the actor about why she created that line

Comment: Why are they doing this? @Valorum

Comment: @RoboticMalevolence - On the face of it, it seems quite opinion-based since you're asking those viewing the question what they think (opinion) rather than what evidence they can find (fact). I've tweaked the language a little to make it more "what evidence do we have of what she thought".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was addressed in [an interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128075256/http://animaniajapan.livedoor.biz/archives/17687653.html) with the film's original (Japanese) voice actor Miyamura Yuuko and the film's producer Ootsuki Toshimichi. She is indeed disgusted **by Shinji's actions.**

The line was supposed to be "*I’d never want to be killed by you of all men, absolutely not!*" but after trying it several times, the director decided that it wasn't particularly suiting the scene. He asked the actress what she thought of the situation (learning that Shinji had masturbated over her) and she came up with a new line "*kimochi warui*" which roughly translates as "*I feel sick*".

> After recording all lines of the movie, I was called to the studio because the final line needed to be revised. Ogata came there too as it was Asuka and Shinji's scene.
>   Asuka's final line was *"Anta nankani korosareru nowa mappira yo!"* in the film 
>   scenario. Annno didn't live with my line no matter how many times I tried. Ogata and 
>   I were at a loss how we should play what Annno wanted to express; she even 
>   tried to ride on me and choke me to meet his demand. He must have been pursuing reality.
>   Concerning the final line we adopted, I'm not sure whether I should say about it in fact.
>   At last Anno asked me "***Miyamura, just imagine you are sleeping in your 
>   bed and a stranger sneaks into your room. He can rape you anytime as you are 
>   asleep but he doesn't. Instead, he masturbates looking at you, when you wake 
>   up and know what he did to you. What do you think you would say?***"
>   I had been thinking he was a strange man, but at that moment ***I felt disgusting. So 
>   I told him that I thought "Disgusting".*** And then he sighed and said "... thought as much." He said. " I thought as much."
>
> <sub><sup>[Animania Blog: Asuka's final line in the Evangelion movie was Miyamura's idea](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128075256/http://animaniajapan.livedoor.biz/archives/17687653.html)</sup></sub>

The American voiceover team (headed by writer/producer/director [Amanda Winn-Lee](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/Amanda_Winn-Lee)) chose to go with "*How disgusting*" as an appropriate alternative, after checking with multiple translators.

> "*Now, there was a lot of controversy as to what this last line should be, and did we do it accurately, and again I asked all three of my translators to look at it [pause] but actually **my friend Mari Kamada was the one that provided me with the best explanation of why the line should be how it is, that it was that in the spoken Japanese language there is no word for "I" so that instead of "I feel sick", in all actuality, the character just said "Feel sick" or instead, how we translated it as "How disgusting"."***
>
> *"But this, once again, huge amounts of research went into making sure
>   we nailed this absolutely right, that we were absolutely comfortable
>   with the line we put here because I knew that all the fans who'd seen
>   the movie before were going to be curious."*
>
> <sub><sup>End of Evanglion: DVD Audio Commentary</sup></sub>

Comment: "How disgusting" isn't just "an appropriate alternative." "How disgusting" is totally what "kimochi warui" means in this context. https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2016/07/kimochi-meaning.html?m=1

Comment: @Kai - The voiceover team debated the meaning at considerable length. Apparently it's not as simple as you're suggesting.

Comment: Then either they were arguing over which definition of kimochi warui to use, or they were unaware of this definition, which even appears in common dictionaries. http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MDJ%B5%A4%BB%FD%A4%C1%A4%AC%B0%AD%A4%A4

Comment: @Kai - It's not a question of definition, but nuance. Even your own dictionary offers some differing definitions; "*bad-feeling; disagreeable; unpleasant; revolting; gross; disgusting*". She could just as easily have said "***Gross!***" and the translation would have been just as accurate.

Comment: My point is that it means disgust in this context, not "I feel sick" which most English speakers would take to mean they feel physically ill. "Disgusting", "gross", and so forth are all valid. You might even translate it as "it makes me sick" which is something an English speaker might say figuratively to mean they find something disgusting.